# Audio API: Fail to resume music and also visualize it. Is there bug in html5-audio?

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have a button. Every time it is clicked, a music is played. When it's clicked the second time, the music resumes. I also want to visualize the music.

So i begin with **html5 audio** (complete code in http://jsfiddle.net/karenpeng/PAW7r/):

```
  $("#1").click(function(){
    audio1.src = '1.mp3';
    audio1.controls = true;
    audio1.autoplay = true;
    audio1.loop = true;

    source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio1);

    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
    });
```

But when it's clicked **more than once**, it console.log error:

```
    Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
```

Then i change to use **web audio API**, and change the source to:

```
    source = context.createBufferSource();
```

The error is gone.

And then, i need to visualize it.
But ironicly, it **only works** in **html5 audio**!

(complete code in http://jsfiddle.net/karenpeng/FvgQF/, it does not work in jsfiddle cuz i dont know how to write processing.js script properly, but it does run on my pc)

```
     var audio = new Audio();
     audio.src = '2.mp3';
     audio.controls = true;
     audio.autoplay = true;
     audio.loop=true;
     var context = new webkitAudioContext();
     var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

     var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
     source.connect(analyser);
     analyser.connect(context.destination);

     var freqData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
     analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqData);

         //visualization using freqData
```

when i change the source to :

```
    source = context.createBufferSource();
```

it does not show anything.

So is there way to visualize it and yet without error and enable it to resume again and again?

Comment: I realize I probably have caused you some confusion today about Web Audio and HTML5 Audio. Sorry about that. Does either of these examples make any sound right now?

Comment: @Oskar Eriksson, it's ok:) Both of them make sounds. But html5 makes error. I found many situations make this type of error so i don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Do you have a live link to share where I can see it in action?

Comment: @Oskar Eriksson, http://jsfiddle.net/karenpeng/PAW7r/  If you copy this and run it in Chrome, you can see it console.log error. This error prevents me from building more things cuz it crashes the browser.But if you use bufferSource which is commented, the error is gone.

Comment: @OskarEriksson, and here's the visualization: http://jsfiddle.net/karenpeng/FvgQF/ it works in my pc but does not work on jsfiddle.net because processing.js library requires this <script type="text/processing" data-processing-target="mycanvas"> and i dont know how to write this on jsfiddle. You could refer to http://processingjs.org/learning/

Comment: @OskarEriksson, oh btw, the error appears when you click the button more than once. i gotta go to bed now, so might not reply you soon.

Comment: Putting it up on the HTML box works: http://jsfiddle.net/FvgQF/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I believe the problem is that you're trying to create a SECOND web audio node for the same media element.  (Your code, when clicked, re-sets the SRC, controls, etc., but it's not creating a new Audio().)  You should either hang on to the MediaElementAudioSourceNode you created, or create new Audio elements.

E.g.:

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext();
var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
var source = null;    
var audio0 = new Audio();

$("#0").click(function(){
    audio0.src = 'http://www.bornemark.se/bb/mp3_demos/PoA_Sorlin_-_Stay_Up.mp3';
    audio0.controls = true;
    audio0.autoplay = true;
    audio0.loop = true;

    if (source==null) {
        source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio0);
        source.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(context.destination);
    }
});​
```

Hope that helps!

-Chris Wilson

Comment: i’ve successfully played it. So it’s time to visualize it. And that’s when i come across another problem: the freqData array i gain is always full of item 0. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Incidentally, you can email me at cwilso at google or gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, this is likely because the `MediaElementSourceNode` may only be able to take in an `Audio` that isn't already playing. The `Audio` object is declared outside of the `click` handler, so you're trying to analyze audio that's in the middle of playing the second time you click.

Note that the API doesn't seem to specify this, so I'm not 100% sure, but this makes intuitive sense.